# Ruby object literals (ala javascript)

Tags: ruby

In ruby you can go

```
a = { }
a['a'] = 82
a['b'] = 'foo'
puts a['a'] # 82
```

I wish I could use dot notation, like javascript.

`puts a.a # 82`

Is there a way to build object literals and access them with dot notation in ruby?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create a [`Struct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html).

```
A = Struct.new(:a, :b)
a = A.new(82, 'foo')
puts a.a
#=> 82
```

**edit:**

you can even do

```
a = { }
a['a'] = 82
a['b'] = 'foo'
Struct.new(*a.keys).new(*a.values)
```

Answer (score 5):

The structure what you need is a [`OpenStruct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) which work the same way as JS object literals. It has overwritten `method_missing` method which allow adding new variables using setter methods.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't have object literals.

Ruby is a class-based object-oriented language. Every object is an instance of a class, and classes are responsible for creating instances of themselves. You don't create objects just by writing them down, you have to ask a class to create an instance of itself by sending it a message (typically called `new`, although that is only a convention).